# while compiling thread program on linux machine it gives "undefined reference " error

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads

Hi I have written a simple program in threads to create 10 threads and execute them normally but when I compile the code on linux machine it gives following errors.. 
   ***/tmp/cc4swqyK.o: In function `main':
   threadcreate1.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to`pthread_create'
   threadcreate1.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status***

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling it as 'gcc -lpthread fileName.c'

You will have to include the header file pthread.h

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

and when compiling, specify the library to link with using '`-l`'option of gcc.